# Alternative mailing methods for website?

Tags: php, email

I have a basic contact form for my website but the free web hosting I use is restricting the use of the mail() function. Are there any alternative methods I can use so users can contact me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't have restrictions on sockets, you can use one [PHP SMTP Class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)

Comment: trying it out now thanks :D, will update

Comment: Any tips on using this? I.e where to put the files, what files to use etc.? It's new to me

Comment: you can use it in any folder you like, just include the class file (class.phpmailer.php) in your script. In the README file in the root, there is a full example, very easy to understand. I don't paste it here because it's a bit long

Comment: OK thanks, I'm including the class file to my mailer php script, hoping for the best :P

Comment: I fixed all the errors I had, but only to be greeted by more :( I'll try tomorrow since its nearly half 11 over here in england. Thanks for all your help :D

Comment: no problem at all, if i can help just write me :) Have a nice night, bye!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mailing library like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to send mails via an external SMTP server, e.g. GMail.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean you can't use a 3rd party mailer.  Can't see any reason why you can't just include PHPmailer  www.phpmailer.worxware.com/